# How do I add a folder to the Library using a UNIX command?

Tags: unix, apple-remote-desktop

I need to add a folder to /user/username/Library/Application Support/Google, on a number of computers.  Is there a way to do it with a UNIX command in ARD, so I don't have to touch each machine?

Answer (score 2):

The command to create a folder is:

```
mkdir "/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/Google/MyFolder"
```

(you'll need to substitute your own folder name ofcourse)

Answer (score 2):

It sure is!

`mkdir '/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/whatever'`

Replace 'username' and 'whatever' appropriately, of course. Also, note that if anything in the path contains single quotes (apostrophes), you'll need to replace each one with `'\''` – I'm using single quotes here to take care of any other quoting issues, and this will end the quote string, put in a quote, and start another (Single-quoted strings don't accept *any* form of escape, even escaping a single quote!).

For more information on this command, type `man mkdir` in Terminal.

For more information on shell quoting, type `man bash` in Terminal, then use `/quoting` to search for "quoting"—this should get you to the appropriate section.